# Unable come out of the search on pressing ESC key

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

The `Angular-Material` based input/text field intend not to come out of the search on pressing ESC button; Is there any tweak for this?

[image]

Expected view on pressing Escape button

[image]

Current Elements panel

[image]

Comment: When you say "come out of the search" what do want to happen? For example, autocomplete (https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete) clears the field. Is that what you mean?

Comment: The active search field should be inactive as what we see before clicking the text field. It seems to be a bug here as well
https://paytm.com/@sennheiser?src=1&q=sennheiser

Comment: Could you tell me what that search element is? It doesn't seem to be an Angular Material element.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the main search element. Is it called searchbox? Where can I find it to test with?

Comment: I used custom css in searchbox but md-input-container brings the angular-material based services.
you can try the same in the search box available in this codepen http://codepen.io/kyleledbetter/pen/gbQOaV

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to test with the actual searchbox element used in https://paytm.com/@sennheiser?src=1&q=sennheiser and shown in your question. Is it possible for you to create a CodePen with that searchbox? Sorry for all the question! But I'm curious to help. :-)

Comment: created a small codepen for this http://codepen.io/prashanthsams/pen/ZpzWxW
Fixing this will help all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of removing focus from an input with the escape key (I think that's what you are trying to achieve) - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/ORLXor?editors=1010#0)

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl" ng-app="MyApp" ng-cloak>
  <md-input-container md-theme="docs-dark" flex="">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input id="myInput" type="text" ng-keydown="inputKeydown($event)">
  </md-input-container>
</div>
```

JS

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular
      .module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])
      .controller('DemoCtrl', DemoCtrl);

  function DemoCtrl ($scope, $element) {
    var myInput = angular.element($element[0].querySelector('#myInput'));
    $scope.inputKeydown = function (event) {
      if (event.key === "Escape") {
        myInput.blur();
     }
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: I need your contact; skype would be fine.. check me in twitter